# VBA: Dims inside a Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use a Vlookup with the line:

```
wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & (vCol - 1) & "],'" & vSheet & "'!C[15]:C[16],2,FALSE"
```

where `vCol as Integer = 9` and `vSheet as String = 082015`

So basically, that line can be rewritten as:

`wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-8],'082015'!C[15]:C[16],2,FALSE)"`

However, I'm getting an "Application-defined or object-defined error" during run-time.

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Set a string equal to what you're setting the formula to, then use debug.print / a msgbox to inform you of the string's value. Does it read out the way you wanted?

Comment: You miss closing bracket after `FALSE`, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Is *vSheet* a string or a worksheet object? Perhaps you need `vSheet.Name` to get the name of the worksheet.

Comment: Use `wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "'=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & (vCol - 1) & "],'" & vSheet & "'!C[15]:C[16],2,FALSE"` and take a look at what gets put into the cell. (note the `'` prefix character and the missing closing bracket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & (vCol  - 1) & "],'" & vSheet & "'!C[15]:C[16],2,FALSE)"
```

Note missing bracket at the end

Comment: Thank you.  The solution is: `wRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-" & (vCol - 1) & "],'" & vSheet & "'!C[15]:C[16],2,FALSE)"`